# How data can be synchronized among multiple linux servers

Tags: linux, database, server

I have basically 4 servers for running the same project. I want make changes in database from UI.

What should I do so that all changes are reflected on all server so that all servers contain the same data.

Comment: You can either have all four servers talk to one single database server, or you can use some form of [replication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_%28computing%29). This question is far to broad to answer properly, we don't even know which database you're using.

Comment: It is probably a question for [superuser](http://superuser.com/) or [database administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) and it heavily depends upon the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use replication in database for your purpose.

Answer (score 4):

You can use data replication. replicate all the data from all four servers at one single location.

Answer (score 2):

Database replication is the frequent electronic copying data from a database in one computer or server to a database in another so that all users share the same level of information. The result is a distributed database in which users can access data relevant to their tasks without interfering with the work of others. The implementation of database replication for the purpose of eliminating data ambiguity or inconsistency among users is known as normalization.